# Trouble with characters encoding

Tags: python, encoding

I am downloading tweets from Italian twitterers for a subsequent analysis. Once downloaded, I store them in a python data frame and then I write them in a file.

On writing in the file, special characters like "è" that exists in Italian language are converted in characters like X8/XE or something like that.

I have tried several encodings like utf8, Latin1 or ISO-8859-1 but the problem persists.

Each line of the dataframe is a user carrying different info like name, screen, name.... and description which is the field I am having problems with.

Here are the lines I use to add the user to the existing data frame:

```
b=pd.DataFrame(np.array([[user.id,
                             user.created_at,
                             user.lang.encode('utf-8'),
                             user.screen_name.encode('utf-8'),
                             user.name.encode('utf-8'),
                             user.location.encode('utf-8'),
                             user.description.encode('utf-8'),
                             user.followers_count,                        
                             user.profile_image_url_https.encode('utf-8')]]), columns=col).append(b, ignore_index=True)
```

And this is the way I write the info in the file

```
b.to_csv(filename, encoding="utf-8")
```

Just after downloading from Twitter, in the data frame I for example can read:

> "La vita è un'opportunità...coglila"

but in the file it gets converted in:

> b"La vita \xc3\xa8 un'opportunit\xc3\xa0...coglila"

What should I do to reconvert it back to the original string?

Comment: How are you trying to save the data in the file ? Are you using the binary mode ?

Comment: It is converting the strings to, so called, 'binary strings'. You can convert these to normal strings, by calling `b"La vita \xc3\xa8 un'opportunit\xc3\xa0...coglila".decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: You should correctly see the bytestring if you print it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try without encoding nor decoding them to utf-8? This should work out of the box. 
If you really want to decode them, then use the .str.decode() method on every Series:

```
b['series_name'] = b['series_name'].str.decode('utf-8')
```

And then save it to csv without any encoding:

```
b.to_csv(filename)
```

Comment: Hi, I had to introduce the coding because I was experiencing another problem. In any case we are now in the right track. the command b"La vita \xc3\xa8 un'opportunit\xc3\xa0...coglila".decode('utf-8') works perfectly. But the command b['series_name'] = b['series_name'].str.decode('utf-8') doesn't. I guess this is because ['series_name'] now contain the STRING   "b'La vita \xc3\xa8 un'opportunit\xc3\xa0...coglila'" Not the binary string.... AGGGGHHHH!!! :-)

Comment: In any case I do not get it: when I read the cvs file, I use encoding "utf-8". A=pd.read_csv(filename, encoding="utf8") It should decode it itself!!!

Comment: Then try decoding it when creating the dataframe : user.lang.decode('utf-8') instead of user.lang.encode('utf-8'). Wait, what type do you get when you do type(user.lang)?

Comment: That's what i was saying. The type is str not binary. This is why the decoding does not work

Comment: b['series_name'] = b['series_name'].str.decode('utf-8') gives a column of NaN. This is because the type of the column is str... Not binary as it should be.... help....

Comment: Then you need to fix this upstream. How do you get the user object?

Comment: I download it directly from Twitter....Are you saying that I have to trash 800.000 tweets I have download it in 20 days???? No please. There must be a way to decode the description.

Comment: The problem cannot be upstream. As I said, in the data frame the description looks ok. The problem is when I write it to a file.